# MySQL - Select values and remove duplicates by table name

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have two tables which have the same structure but another names (in first table I store default values, in second table I store saved values by user).

I select these values using union all:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_default` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `table_saved`
```

Structure of table_default:

```
| ID | SOME_VAL |
|  1 | def_val  |
|  2 | def_val  |
|  3 | def_val  |
```

Structure of table_saved:

```
| ID | SOME_VAL |
|  1 |   test   |
|  3 |   text   |
```

And now, when I using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_default` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `table_saved`
```

I got:

```
| ID | SOME_VAL |
|  1 | def_val  |
|  2 | def_val  |
|  3 | def_val  |
|  1 |   test   |
|  3 |   text   |
```

But I want to get unique values by ID. Table_saved is more important so when select return duplicates I want to remove always record from table_default.
So finally I want to get:

```
| ID | SOME_VAL |
|  2 | def_val  | --> from TABLE_DEFAULT because this record (by ID) is not exist in table_saved
|  1 |   test   | --> from TABLE_SAVED
|  3 |   text   | --> from TABLE_SAVED
```

I can't use GROUP BY `id` because I don't know which record will be remove (sometime GROUP BY remove duplicate from table_default but sometimes GROUP BY also remove duplicates from table_saved) so I can't manage this.

Is it possible to remove duplicates (something like GROUP BY) using table name and row name ? Or maybe somebody has another idea. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to always retain all records from `table_saved`, plus records from `table_default` having IDs not appearing in `table_saved`.  One approach is to use a left join to find the unique records from `table_default`.  Then union that with all records from `table_saved`.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.SOME_VAL
FROM table_default t1
LEFT JOIN table_saved t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, SOME_VAL
FROM table_saved;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a default value is always present you could use a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE:

```
SELECT d.ID, COALESCE(s.SOME_VAL, d.SOME_VAL) AS SOME_VAL
FROM table_default d
LEFT JOIN table_saved s USING(ID)
```